# Call instances of custom object with different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call an instance of a custom object twice with one parameter different, the problem is if I set its config property it changes accordingly if I create 2 instances, but if I don't specify the property when calling the second instance of the object, it inherits the set parameter from the first instance.

I want the second instance to use the default parameter unless it is manually set when calling it.

I tried making an elem variable and prepend it to queried elements but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="test"><p>test</p></div>
</div>

<div class="parent-second">
<div class="test"><p>test</p></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {

// Utility
if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
    Object.create = function( obj ) {
        function F() {};
        F.prototype = obj;
        return new F();
    };
}

var objTest = {

    config: {
        value: 'some text'
    },

    init: function(elem, config) {

        var self = this;
        this.elem = elem;

        $.extend(this.config, config);

        this.doIt();
    },

    doIt: function() {
        var self = this;
        $(self.elem + ' .test p').text(this.config.value);
        console.log($(self.elem + ' .test p'));
    }

};

var parent = Object.create( objTest );

parent.init('.parent', {
    value: 'first div text'
});

// if you comment out the value parameter from the following instance, it will inherit from previous object instance
var parentSecond = Object.create( objTest );

parentSecond.init('.parent-second', {
    value: 'second div text'
});




})(); // end self invoking function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your config object is getting shared among all the instances of your object. Hence you must create a new config object for each instance.

```
    var objTest = {

        init: function(elem, config) {

            var self = this;
            this.elem = elem;
            if(!this.config)
            {
                this.config = {
                value: 'some text'
                };
            }
            $.extend(this.config, config);

            this.doIt();
        },

        doIt: function() {
            var self = this;
            $(self.elem + ' .test p').text(this.config.value);
            console.log($(self.elem + ' .test p'));
        }

    };
```

This would work just fine for you. Though I would prefer the prototype approach for this.

```
function objTest ()
{
    //you could also merge init function in this constructor
    this.config = {
        value: 'some text'
    };
}
objTest.prototype = {
    init = function (elem, config) {
       var self = this;
        this.elem = elem;
        if(!this.config)
        {
            this.config = {
            value: 'some text'
            };
        }
        $.extend(this.config, config);

        this.doIt();

    },
    doIt: function() {
        var self = this;
        $(self.elem + ' .test p').text(this.config.value);
        console.log($(self.elem + ' .test p'));
    }

}  


var parent = new objTest();

parent.init('.parent', {
    value: 'first div text'
});

var parentSecond = new objTest();

parentSecond.init('.parent-second', {
    value: 'second div text'
});
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work with prototyping. I wanted to use that from the start but wasn't sure how to incorporate default values and options. Also, the default values should be set inside the main constructor function only, not its init method (values from the init method don't seem to do anything if no values are set when calling the instance)